# Does promise need call stack to be empty to get resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, event-loop

I used `process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails` as shown below to get promise status and I used node `dns` module functions that returns promise. I then queried whether that promise is resolved in synchronous manner, but result always showed promise is not resolved even though answer usually comes in milliseconds.

```
const { Resolver } = require('dns').promises;
const resolver = new Resolver();
 
 
let a = resolver.resolve4('example.org');
 
let time = Date.now();
 
while (time + 10000 > Date.now()) {
  console.log(process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails(a));
}
```

My question was do we need stack to be empty so that even internally promise is marked as resolved. I know that `then` handler runs when stack is empty, but does internally promise is marked as resolved only when stack is empty?

If resolution of promise needs stack to be empty to get marked as resolved when stack is empty, how am I able to add a `debugger;` statement and wait and when I inspect promise (after waiting for a while with code still paused) it is resolved, even though stack is not empty as code is paused.

For example:

```
let a = fetch('google.com'); 
debugger;
console.log("hello");
```

I can now wait and see that `a` is fulfilled even though I have not resumed the code, so if I have not resumed the code and stack remains full, how is `a` then getting fulfilled?

Answer (score 2):

> Do we need stack to be empty so that even internally promise is marked as resolved?

No, the runtime can mark promises that it created internally as resolved at any time (though it probably needs some kind of semaphore lock on the job queue), as seen with `fetch` in your example.

However, the *dns/promises* `resolve` method does not construct an **internal** promise. It is [created from JS code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8ba54e50496a6a5c21d93133df60a9f7cb6c46ce/lib/internal/dns/promises.js#L266) and the resolved from [an event handler](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8ba54e50496a6a5c21d93133df60a9f7cb6c46ce/lib/internal/dns/promises.js#L249-L263) that is <s>called</s> scheduled from the native code. This handler code does indeed need an empty stack to run, so it has not run by the time when your code was blocked for one second and inspects the promise.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it helps clear lot of my doubt, I was thinking the same. 

Do we have internal promise in nodeJs, I want to check the state of that promise in a loop using `process.binding('util').getPromiseDetails`.

Comment: I don't know, but why would you want to do that? If it's just for demonstration purposes, just create a fulfilled promise with `Promise.resolve`.

Comment: I want to see that in working, I can use `Promise.resolve` but there is no way in `Promise.resolve` where I can wait for some milliseconds and then that promise is resolved. I want to log things and then in while loop after a while see that promise is now resolved. It will confirm that internally C++ code marks promise as resolved even though stack is not empty.

Comment: You probably could just call `resolve()` directly from the loop (halfway through) in the demo code. I do not know whether nodejs resolves any promises from C++ code - but the source is open so you should be able to find them if there are any.

Comment: @CollinD `new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))` won't work if a loop is running as JavaScript is single threaded. I was just trying to see if any promise is resolved from C++ code as bergi said.

Comment: @Bergi So my understanding is (correct me if I am wrong), that fetch in browser was getting resolved from C++ code and so it did not required stack to be empty, but the promises that I used in nodejs was being resolved from JavaScript itself so needed stack to be empty.

Comment: @SurajJain yes.

Comment: @Bergi If I call `resolve()` from JavaScript then the promise is resolved then and there, my doubt was that if I used native JavaScript function that returns promise and as soon as that promise is returned I run a loop, for example when I fetched a resource using `fetch` and then ran a loop now behind the scene fetch will get the data, my doubt was even though my JavaScript code is running, does the promise that fetch returned will be marked as resolved through fetch code (in c++) and if I had a way to inspect promise object properties, will state come as fulfilled if I checked in that loop.

Comment: @SurajJain Isn't that answered with "yes" already? Only trouble is that you cannot "run a loop behind the scene" with JS.

Comment: I meat behind the scenes fetch will fetch the data and our loop has blocked main thread. Now as the main thread is blocked, and suppose data has been received will C++ code mark the promise as resolved internally while main thread is blocked with the while loop. Now if I had some way to query that promise state in my while loop, if C++ code can mark the promise as resolved even though main thread is blocked with event loop, if I continue querying the promise in my while loop, will query result with promise is resolved after a while. I suppose as you said above, answer would be yes.